# SQL field with an foreign id from two tables

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am constructing a postgressql database with sqlalchemy. I was wondering if it is possible to have a structure like this:

Two tables consisting of persons, and organisations.

```
Table - Person - 
person_id, name
1,         Jeffery
2,         Frank

Table - Org -
org_id, name
a,      Pepsi
b,      Microsoft
```

A third table of addresses or either persons or organisations:

```
Table - Addresses -
address_id, type_of_id, (either person_id or org_id), addresses
1,          person,     1, "2 Jeffery way"
2,          person,     1, "7 Holland Avenue"
3,          org,        b, "1 Microsoft way"
4,          person,     2, "2 Frank Street"
```

Is this possible with postgres? And how do I write it into sqlalchemy python code?

Update:

I believe this is called a Polymorphic association as in:
[Possible to do a MySQL foreign key to one of two possible tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441001/possible-to-do-a-mysql-foreign-key-to-one-of-two-possible-tables)

Comment: This is actually possible, although, from a *relational* point of view, doesn't make much sense. You would normally have the tables `Person` and `Org` have a column `address_id`, referencing `Addresses(address_id)` and let the adresses be addresses (no person org, or person_id there).

Comment: What if I have multiple addresses per person, and multiple addresses for organizations?

Comment: I'd go for two "link tables": one for `person_x_address (person_id, address_id)`, and another one for `organization_x_address (organization_id, address_id)`. It will be *cleaner* than most other options.

Answer (score 1):

Your question consists out of two parts:

1. Create a union of the persons and organisations table.
2. Add the type of entity (person/organisation) to the table.

The first part can be done using union_all. More information on this can be found at:

- [How to concatenate unrelated queries in SqlAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44910975/how-to-concatenate-unrelated-queries-in-sqlalchemy/44916786#44916786)
- http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html

the second part, adding the type of entity (person/organisation) can be achieved using literal_column. For more information on this:

- [How do I select literal values in an sqlalchemy query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533146/how-do-i-select-literal-values-in-an-sqlalchemy-query) (see comment in regards to quoting the text when using postgresql)

The following is a short example combining these elements:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()


## Define sample models


class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    person_id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String(250))

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return '[{person_id}] - {name}'.format(person_id=self.person_id, name=self.name)


class Orqanisation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'organisation'
    organisation_id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String(250))

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return '[{organisation_id}] - {name}'.format(organisation_id=self.organisation_id, name=self.name)


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///')
session = sessionmaker()
session.configure(bind=engine)
ex_ses = session()
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

## Create sample data

# http://listofrandomnames.com/ for something else then A,B,...
names = ['Virgil', 'Ina', 'Oleta', 'Suzette', 'Usha', 'Ilda', 'Lorean', 'Cinthia', 'Sheba', 'Waneta', 'Donnette']

organisations = ['stackoverflow','Cross validated','Meta stack overflow','Area 51']

# Create persons
for name in names:
    ex_ses.add(Person(name=name))

# Create organisations
for org in organisations:
    ex_ses.add(Orqanisation(name=org))

ex_ses.commit()

# queries
print('Persons:')
for person in ex_ses.query(Person).all():
    print('* ',person)

'''
Persons:
*  [1] - Virgil
*  [2] - Ina
*  [3] - Oleta
*  [4] - Suzette
*  [5] - Usha
*  [6] - Ilda
*  [7] - Lorean
*  [8] - Cinthia
*  [9] - Sheba
*  [10] - Waneta
*  [11] - Donnette
'''

print('Organisations:')
for org in ex_ses.query(Orqanisation).all():
    print('* ',org)

'''
Organisations:
*  [1] - stackoverflow
*  [2] - Cross validated
*  [3] - Meta stack overflow
*  [4] - Area 51
'''

# Query combining tables, adding type of entity

from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import literal_column

persons = ex_ses.query(Person.person_id, Person.name,literal_column("'person'").label('type'))
organisations = ex_ses.query(Orqanisation.organisation_id, Orqanisation.name,literal_column("'Organisation'").label('type'))

print('Persons - Organisations:')
for pers_org in persons.union_all(organisations).all():
    print('* {id} - {name} (type: {type})'.format(id=pers_org[0],name=pers_org[1],type=pers_org[2]))

'''
Persons - Organisations:
* 1 - Virgil (type: person)
* 2 - Ina (type: person)
* 3 - Oleta (type: person)
* 4 - Suzette (type: person)
* 5 - Usha (type: person)
* 6 - Ilda (type: person)
* 7 - Lorean (type: person)
* 8 - Cinthia (type: person)
* 9 - Sheba (type: person)
* 10 - Waneta (type: person)
* 11 - Donnette (type: person)
* 1 - stackoverflow (type: Organisation)
* 2 - Cross validated (type: Organisation)
* 3 - Meta stack overflow (type: Organisation)
* 4 - Area 51 (type: Organisation)
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapting from: http://www.duanqu.tech/questions/2898814/sqlalchemy-polymorphic-association
and http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import as_declarative, declared_attr
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Integer, Column, \
    String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, relationship
from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists, create_database
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
import uuid


@as_declarative()
class Base(object):
    # Set the tablenames
    # to the class names
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()
    # give an id to each class
    id = Column(UUID, default=lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()), primary_key=True)
# Base = declarative_base()


class EntityInterface(Base):
    discriminator = Column(String)

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": discriminator}


class Address(Base):
    street = Column(String)
    city = Column(String)
    zip = Column(String)
    entity_id = Column(UUID, ForeignKey(EntityInterface.id),
                       default=lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()))
    entity = relationship(EntityInterface)

    def __repr__(self):
        return ("%s(street=%r, city=%r, zip=%r, company=%r)" %
                (self.__class__.__name__, self.street, self.city,
                 self.zip, self.entity))


class Person(EntityInterface):
    id = Column(UUID, ForeignKey(EntityInterface.id),
                default=lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "Person"}


class Organization(EntityInterface):
    id = Column(UUID, ForeignKey(EntityInterface.id),
                default=lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "Organization"}


engine = create_engine(
    'postgresql://paul_tsc:paul123@localhost/' + "poly_testing",
    echo=False)

# if it doesn't exist, create it
if not database_exists(engine.url):
    create_database(engine.url)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = Session(engine)

address1 = Address(street='test-1', city="Detroit", zip="56785")
address2 = Address(street='test-2', city="Phoenix", zip="110322")
address3 = Address(street='test-3', city="Washington", zip="432414")

org1 = Organization(name="Org-1 TEST")
org2 = Organization(name="Org-2 TEST")
person1 = Person(name="Person-1 TEST")
person2 = Person(name="Person-2 TEST")

address1.entity = org1
address2.entity = person1
address3.entity = person1

session.add_all([address1, address2, address3])

session.commit()

address3.entity = org2

session.commit()

print("PRINTING, TOTAL = %s" % session.query(Address).count())
for address in session.query(Address):
    print("ADDRESS = %s" % address)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to model this in a relational database:

1. **Relationship table**

   ```
   CREATE TABLE address_assignment (
      person_id integer REFERENCES person,
      org_id text REFERENCES org,
      address_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES address,
      CHECK (person_id IS     NULL AND org_id IS NOT NULL
          OR person_id IS NOT NULL AND org_id IS     NULL),
      UNIQUE (person_id, org_id, address_id)
   );
   ```

   This model would be particularly useful if different entities can share one address.
2. **“Poor man's superclass”**

   Create a table that implements a superclass for person and organization, maybe containing all common attributes:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE located_entity (
      locent_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      name text NOT NULL
   );
   ```

   Both `person` and `org` get a foreign key to `located_entity`, and you can implement the relationship with `address` by also adding a foreign key to `located_entity` to `address`.

   If you usually look up persons by their address rather than addresses by person, you could consider adding the foreign keys between `located_entity` and `person` or `org` person in the other direction, with a similar check constraint as in solution 1.

Comment: I implemented option 2 above